# Cmdlet does not respect -ErrorAction flag or continue correctly when run

Tags: powershell, error-handling, active-directory

I'm working on updating our computer AD join script to check for duplicate objects in AD but having some issues with it.

My main problem is I want to know if an AD computer object of the given name (-Identity) is null, but rather than simply checking the value as I expect (C# background) the script errors when trying to check because the object does not exist.

Naturally my next attempt was setting the ErrorActionPreference. I wanted to do it just for this cmdlet with -ErrorAction but for whatever reason the cmdlet seems to completely ignore the flag and instead follow the $ErrorActionPreference variable regardless. Snippet below:

```
if ((Get-ADComputer -ErrorAction 'SilentlyContinue' -Identity "whatever") -eq $null) { Write-Host "success" }
```

But with the code above it doesn't continue. If I change $ErrorActionPreference to 'SilentlyContinue' or Continue/Inquire and tell the code to continue, it finishes with no errors shown as expected but it **does not complete the Write-Host**. This means whatever function I might put after the 'if' will not complete, either.

I'm fairly new to PowerShell so I'm sure I'm misunderstanding how some of this functionality works with the errors. From some other snippets I've seen I might need to swap to Try/Catch but that feels incredibly clunky for something this basic. Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Not familiar Get-ADComputer but if its erroring out when nothing is found with the -identity flag, might be fine to put it in a try..catch, could effectively replicate your if statement

Answer (score 0):

Powershell doesn't complicate things. `Get-AdComputer` will error if it cant find the target, so just test for success.

```
If (Get-AdComputer -Identity "whatever" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue) { Write-Host "Success" }
```

If you want to supress the error that will occur when not finding an object, use `-ErrorAction` with the above or to handle the error yourself use `-ErrorAction Stop` along with either `Else {Throw...}` or `Try...Catch` options.

I tend to use `Try...Catch` for all but the simplest scripts because of the control it gives you over output - the `$_` variable in the `Catch` block contains the error code.

```
Try {
    Get-AdComputer -Identity "whatever" -ErrorAction Stop
    Write-Host "Success"
}
Catch {
    Write-Host "Failed with error: $_"
}
```

Comment: In your code snippet above you run into the exact same issue I mentioned in my question.

That -ErrorAction is completely ignored in PowerShell. You can test yourself- just run that line of code exactly as is complete with the "whatever". Whether you have it set to SilentlyContinue or Stop it will give the exact same results- whatever your $ErrorActionPreferences variable is set to.

Comment: You can, for instance, add an extra Write-Host "Failure" outside of the curly braces. When running with both continue and stop options, it will write Failure to the console.

Comment: What EXACTLY are you trying to achieve?

Comment: If a computer object of the given name does *not* exist in AD already, create it. Else, pause and give feedback that the object already exists. I worked around the problems with -ErrorAction by using Try/Catch instead even though it's much more involved. It's frustrating that, compared to eg C#, trying to compare to null throws an error rather than just continuing. Really sloppy.